# Wordpress Display Different Content On Page Based On Request Parameters

Tags: wordpress

On a wordpress page, how do I display different content based on request parameters.

For example ?sex=male & ?sex=female would display different content.
So how do I put a conditional operator on a page based on request parameters.

Comment: `if( $_GET['sex'] === 'male' ) { echo 'male'; }`. Do the same for female

Comment: Can i put php code directly on the page.

Comment: Not sure which content you are talking about, so where you will use it depends on what you mean by content. If it is static content, you can directly add it to your template file where you would want to add the content

Comment: Within each if i would like to include forms by means of shortcodes for example [gravityform id="3" name="male" title="false" description="false"]

Comment: Will post an answer based on that

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have already set up your `query_vars` and registered them.

You can get use the `$_GET`  parameter to get the value from the custom query variable

```
if( isset( $_GET['sex'] ) ) {
    if( $_GET['sex'] == 'male' ) {
        //Display shortcode for male
    }elseif( $_GET['sex']  == 'female' ) {
        //Display shortcode for female
    }
}
```